# Unable to get webpage size using C#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, content-length, http-content-length

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snnHg.jpg)

Experts,

I'm using below piece of code to get the document size but I get incorrect length since the browser profiler shows 200 KB size but I get  50 KB. Can someone please help?

```
        string URL = "https://www.google.com/";
        Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            respStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        }
        byte[] data = resultStream.GetBuffer();
        int length1 = data.Length;
        decimal length = data.LongLength / 1024;
```

Note:Content-length returns -1.

Comment: PFA attached image . The image (has browser profiler)  indicate the field which I'm looking for.

Comment: The server may be defaulting to http 1.1 which is chunk mode and net only works with stream mode.  So set your request to http 1.0 before GetResponse.  Try :             request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: BTW: use `resultStream.ToArray()` not `resultStream.GetBuffer()`